# ILGenerator: How to add boolean to the stack

Tags: boolean, reflection.emit

Here is the way I can put float value to the stack(in C#):

```
ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R4, (float)12.5);
```

How can I put boolean value to the stack by using Emit method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no representation of a boolean value on the evaluation stack. The bool, char, byte, ushort, uint, and their signed variants are all represented as a 4-byte signed integer (i4).

True:

```
ldc.i4.1
```

False:

```
ldc.i4.0
```

Comment: If everything is represented as 4-byte signed integer, are there memory advantages to use byte instead of ushort (for example) if the values are not going above byte max value ?

Comment: @Hybris95 The evaluation stack is not the same as fields of an object. Fields (especially those in a struct) and elements of arrays can be more tightly packed to save memory.